I want to use in another context the frame title color
I'm using Beamer w/o themes, and I'm pretty satisfied with the output, less is more? but now I'd like to customize my blocks, using as the background colors lighter versions of the color of the frame titles.
How can I reference the color Beamer uses for the frame titles?
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
% \setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=???}
% \setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=??}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Intro}
  \begin{block}{Test test}
    Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test,  test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test.    
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



You could use the frametitle colour:
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=frametitle,bg=frametitle.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=frametitle,bg=frametitle.fg!10!bg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Intro}
  \begin{block}{Test test}
    Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test,  test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test.    
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Alternatively use the rose colour theme, which will change the block colours to lighter versions of the structure colour, which is the grandparent of the colour used by the frame title:
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Intro}
  \begin{block}{Test test}
    Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test,  test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test.    
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



After checking the results I found that the shadow, and also the rounded corners, are too loud in my un-themed slides, so I ended using bg=structure.fg!10!white and bg=structure.fg!6!white.
